# How should we understand this conversation about the use of the phrase "you do you"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Person: "Dude, I just dropped, like, 20 bucks on a scooter.
>
> Person: "Cool, you do you."

While I tried to google the usage of the phrase "[you do you](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=You%20do%20You)", I bumped into the example above. I don't quite get it. The conversation doesn't seem to make sense to me. Maybe it's because I don't get the exact meaning of the first sentence "I just dropped 20 bucks on a scooter"? But indeed it looks pretty straightforward. Can someone help me to understand the conversation? What's it all about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you've tried to look up "you do you" I assume you have a general idea of its meaning. You indicate that the explanation on that Urban Dictionary page confuses you. The popular meaning of "you do you" or "do you" is very simple: When someone says that to you, they mean to tell you that they don't necessarily agree with you but they can't change your mind and won't even want to attempt to change your mind. It's a slightly ruder, newer, and more millennial-sounding version of "[suit yourself](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/suit-yourself)" and "[to each their own](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to%20each%20his%20own)".

But there is a lesser common meaning of "cool", "you did good", "good job", or "be yourself". The Urban Dictionary example goes like this: Person A tells their friend they bought a scooter for $20. Their friend Person B thinks it is a good deal, so they tell Person A: "You did a good job, just like you always do." I don't hear this sense of "you do you" used very often in real life. When I hear "you do you", it is always used in a sarcastic way, in the first sense I mention above.

Comment: so ''drop'' here means "to pay"?

Comment: @dan Yeah, or "spend". See [Merriam Webster's definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drop) under transitive verb, 6b.

Comment: I think even in the positive meaning it still implies that the act in question was disagreeable to some extent, even if you ultimately approve of it. So if I got that response to something I was happy and confident about, I'd be a bit irked, even if it was meant in an encouraging way.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski More context would reveal that either the speaker of "you do you" was in disagreement or support of the action. It can be fully supportive in the case of a 3rd party being against the action and a friend says "you do you" to mean, "don't care what others think, I think you made the right decision for yourself."

Comment: @JayA.Little Sure, but even if meant supportively it's still awkward to hear if you had no idea there were any third parties against the action. It's like saying "That's brave of you" - supportive, yes, but probably not a good response to "Alice and I just got married", for example.

Answer (score 2):

"You do you" can be used when giving up an argument as Eddie Kal answered but it has a more positive meaning as well.

The first definition that you linked to says:

> "the act of doing what one believes is the right decision, being oneself"

It can be used to say, "go for it!" or "put yourself first" or "take care of yourself" or even "treat yourself".

> Person: "Dude, I just dropped, like, 20 bucks on a scooter.
> Person: "Cool, you do you."

So when I read this example, I hear a more positive response. Here is the same conversation how I would interpret it:

> Person: "Dude, I just bought a scooter for $20."
> Person: "That's great. Do what makes you happy."

Answer (score 1):

The conversation makes no sense to me.

> The phrase **You, do you** means **be yourself**, which is an odd response to someone telling you they just spent $20 on scooter but I imagine in some contexts it would make sense.

> A similar phrase is **You do?  Do You?** which is a way of questioning someone's claims.